# In Python,Excel,Pandas, I Need to move row based on Date to new sheet, but getting date error

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime, timedelta

so I have an excel report that is run weekly that we manually modify. I have created a Python scrip to remove unwanted data and format it. No I have a request that I need to copy data that is 1 year or older from today, 2 years, 3years and so on. not a programmer so bare with me.

I import the Excel

```
>excel_workbook = 'Excel.xlsx'
sheet1 = pd.read_excel(excel_workbook, sheet_name='Sheet1', keep_default_na= False, index_col=0,
                       parse_dates=['DT RECD'])
```

then when i try to set date tp format i get this:

```
today = pd.datetime.now().date()
print(today)
oneYear = today - pd.Timedelta.days(365) #timedelta(days=365)
print(oneYear)
twoYear = today - pd.Timedelta.days(730) #timedelta(days=730)
print(twoYear)
errors:

pandas.core.arrays.datetimelike.InvalidComparison: 730 days, 0:00:00

raise TypeError(f"Invalid comparison between dtype={left.dtype} and {typ}")
TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and timedelta
```

how do I match dates so I can State something like OverOneYear = <= oneyear and >= twoyear on Column 'DT RECD'

so i have made the changes:

```py
today = datetime.date.today()
oneYear = today - pd.DateOffset(years=1)
twoYear = today - pd.DateOffset(years=2)
Output:
2021-03-01
2020-03-01 00:00:00
2019-03-01 00:00:00
```

Oringinal Time Stamp
MM/DD/YYY

after changes
2020-03-01 00:00:00

Sample Data set
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWMcI.png)

Trying to filter

```py
YearOne[YearOne['DT RECD'].between(oneYear, twoYear)]
print(YearOne)
```

no error - But date 2021-03-01(was this after import "parse_dates=['DT RECD']") does not match 2020-03-01 00:00:00, i do not need the 00:00:00. if i can drop it i think it will filter just fine.

It is in datetime64[ns]
sheet1.dtypes
FINISH                  object
LENGTH                  object
Qty on Hand              int64
Unit Cost              float64
DT RECD         datetime64[ns]
PRODUCED                object
Status                  object

Comment: See my edit below with conversion without the 00:00:00.  If that still doesn't work, you have to check what datatype is the values in column "DT RECD" now.  Whether they are in string or in datetime64 format.  I mean the data that have already been read into DataFrame, not the source file.  So you have to check the DataFrame contents.

Comment: Use `YearOne['DT RECD'] = pd.to_datetime([YearOne['DT RECD'])` if it is not already in datatime64 format.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your setting of `oneYear` and `twoYear` as follows:

```
oneYear = today - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)
twoYear = today - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=2)
```

If you want to select for dates in Column 'DT RECD' within the last one year and 2 years, you can use:  (assuming df is the name of DataFrame)

```
df_selected = df[df['DT RECD'].between(oneYear, twoYear))   # extract into new variable
print(df_selected)                                          # view the selected result
```

**Edit:**

If you want to keep the dates in `datetime.date` format instead of `Timestamp` format, add the following 2 lines in addition to the above:

```
oneYear = oneYear.to_pydatetime().date()
twoYear = twoYear.to_pydatetime().date()
```

Comment: So how do i drop the 00:00:00 in "oneYear = today - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)" which results in "2020-03-01 00:00:00", i get no errors just no data is changed cause i think the filter is expecting the 00:00:00

Comment: Would you please share your codes of data change ?

Comment: Could you also share some sample data especially the date fields.

Comment: here is what i have:
```python
today = datetime.date.today()
oneYear = today - pd.DateOffset(years=1)
Results = 2020-03-01 00:00:00

YearOne = pd.DataFrame(sheet1)
YearOne[YearOne['DT RECD'].between(oneYear, twoYear)]
print(YearOne)
```

Comment: @shughes011 Edited the answer to include formatting the dates to your desired format.  Please check.

Comment: Please check with the following codes:  `YearOneSelected = YearOne[YearOne['DT RECD'].between(oneYear, twoYear)]    print(YearOneSelected)`    That is, you have to assign the selected DataFrame to a new variable and print the new variable

Comment: this is the date
|LOT NUMBER |FINISH     | DT RECD
|471359  | AL  | 07/23/08
|71378301         | CR  | 05/18/18

Comment: Seems the data include years 2008 and 2018.  Make sure you get data to be selected longer than one year and less than 2 years.

Comment: @shughes011  Please edit your original question to supplement with more information instead of trying to edit the supplementary information onto my answer.